# Does Quartz2D test intersection of rect by line before drawing it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm drawing a big scheme that consist of a lot of lines. I do it in the `drawRect:` method of `UIView`. The scheme is larger than the layer of view and I check each line and draw it only if it intersects the visible rect. But at one moment I thought, should I do this? Maybe Quartz is already doing this test?

So the question is:
When I use function `CGContextAddLineToPoint()` does the `Core Graphics` tests this line for intersection with layer rect or it just draw it anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use function `CGContextAddLineToPoint()` does the Core Graphics tests this line for intersection with layer rect or it just draw it anyway?

No, it will not suppress the `lineto`, because that's just one segment in a subpath. A subpath may intersect the rect even if one of its line segments does not. You may be drawing only one line per subpath, but Quartz doesn't know that until you `moveto` for a new subpath.

As for whether *you* should test the lines' intersection of the rect, [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW53) says:

> Views that implement a `drawRect:` method should always check the rectangle passed to the method and use it to limit the scope of their drawing operations. Because drawing is a relatively expensive operation, limiting drawing in this way is a good way to improve performance.

I think we can reasonably interpret this to mean that you should, indeed, check whether the lines intersect the rect and skip those that don't.